# VBA Adding a class to a collection

Tags: vba, collections

I have a class module called Holding. In it are several public variables. My code is this:

```
Dim holdings as Collection
Dim h as Holding

Set holdings = new Collection

For i = 1 to last
    Set h = new Holding

    h.x = y
    '... etc

    holdings.Add(h)
Next i
```

This gives me error "object doesnt support this property or method" on the `holdings.Add(h)` line, but everywhere I look, it gives this exact example of how to achieve this. What am I missing?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Remove the parentheses.

```
holdings.Add h
```

Otherwise you are trying to add to the collection the value of the default property of your `Holding` instance, and it doesn't have a default property.