# Excel Macro - hide comment after edit

Tags: excel, vba

I have this for entering a comment on a excel worksheet when user insert C or P, and I need to hide the comment after edit.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim KeyCells As Range


    Set KeyCells = Range("A1:S1000")

    If Not Application.Intersect(KeyCells, Range(Target.Address)) _
           Is Nothing Then

            Select Case Range(Target.Address)
                Case "C":
                    minhaCelula = Target.Address
                    Range(minhaCelula).AddComment ("")
                    Range(minhaCelula).Comment.Visible = True
                Case "P":
                    minhaCelula = Target.Address
                    Range(minhaCelula).AddComment ("")
                    Range(minhaCelula).Comment.Visible = True

            End Select


    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some problems with that code:

- `Select Case Range(Target.Address)` doesn't make sense - it takes the `Target` range, takes its address and creates a range from that address, which points to the original `Target` range, and finally VB takes the default property of that range, because its not being used in an object reference context. So the whole thing should be replaced with `Target.Value`.
- Later same thing happens to `minhaCelula`.
- Code under `"C"` and `"P"` is the same and should be placed under the same `Case` branch.
- Colons are not used in VB's `Select Case`.
- `AddComment` should be called [without parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6331147/11683). Even better, you should benefit from the fact `AddComment` returns the reference to the added comment, so you can directly use that (in which case you must keep the parentheses).

So that should be rewriteen as:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("A1:S1000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "C", "P"
                Target.AddComment("").Visible = True
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

---

As for the question, when you use `Comment.Visible`, Excel stops managing the comment's visibility. To leave the management on Excel side, make the comment's shape visible instead:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not Application.Intersect(Me.Range("A1:S1000"), Target) Is Nothing Then
        Select Case Target.Value
            Case "C", "P"
                With Target.AddComment("").Shape
                    .Visible = msoTrue
                    .Select
                End With
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```