# Get list of all properties for an object

Tags: excel, vba

Is there a way to get a list of all valid properties for a given object?

If I wanted to start at cell a1, and go down and assign a1, a2, a3, all of the valid properties for let's say a worksheet object for example, is that something that can be done? I can't find any:

```
list = object.enumproperties
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Look in Object Browser (Ctrl + F2)

Comment: Well, yeah. I know about the object browser. But I need to be able to fill a worksheet with the properties.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Tools - References - `TypeLib Information`.

Then:

```
Sub DumpProperties(ByVal o As Object)

  Dim t As TLI.TLIApplication
  Set t = New TLI.TLIApplication

  Dim ti As TLI.TypeInfo
  Set ti = t.InterfaceInfoFromObject(o)

  Dim mi As TLI.MemberInfo, i As Long
  For Each mi In ti.Members
    i = i + 1
    ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1).Value = mi.Name
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: I had to download the DLL from a shady source (and regsvr32 it) but the sub works great, thanks!

Comment: I get "Wrong Number of arguments" when calling
DumpProperties(myObject) within another subs loop.

Is there a specific method to running this sub?

Comment: @KenIngram There is not. Did you include [unwanted parentheses](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331106/11683)?

Comment: I was. Leaving off the parens I got a new error. "ActiveX component can't create object" -> Set t = New TLI.TLIApplication

Comment: Yep. I guess that's the problem. WTF? So, just left hanging with no access to viewing Object properties....jfc

Comment: @KenIngram For viewing properties you have Object Browser, and you can add the object to the Watch pane that will also show properties. Depending on the object, you may also create a vbscript file to create and examine the properties, then you would use `Set t = CreateObject("TLI.TLIApplication")` instead of `= New TLI.TLIApplication`.

Comment: @GSerg The TypeLib Information DLL is not on my Reference list, and when I try to add it (I can find it in C:\Windows\System32) I get the error "Can't add a reference to the specified file". Any ideas how to get around this?

I tried using `Declare ... Lib "typelib" ...` but that didn't help either.

Comment: @BillWallis Are you running 64-bit Excel?

Comment: @GSerg No, I am running 32-bit.

Comment: @BillWallis Then you should be able to add it. On my 64-bit Windows and 32-bit Office, it's located in Windows\SysWow64\TBLINF32.DLL.

Comment: @GSerg The DLL that I was looking for was typelib.dll -- I cannot find the tblinf32.dll file in my C:\Windows\SysWow64 or my C:\Windows\System32 folders. Do I need to download this from somewhere?

Comment: @BillWallis Actually I'm not sure which component installs it, I always thought it came with Windows. I also made a typo, it's TLBINF32.dll.

Comment: @GSerg No worries, I can do without it for the time being (I cannot find tlbinf32.dll either). Thank you for your help though, I may pick this up later!

Comment: I am trying to reproduce this. But at `Set t = New TLI.TLIApplication` I get a `Class not registered` error. I have added a reference to tlbinf32.dll. Does anyone have any suggestion what could be wrong?

Comment: This used to work when I was on windows 8 but, I think since my work computer was upgraded to windows 10, it stopped working. I'm getting back into software development lately and this functionality was just, so so useful. Does anyone know how to get this working again, and without having administrator access to one's PC ?

Comment: @Shodan There should be no problem on Windows 10. Are you using 64-bit Office?

Comment: I tried with `Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.References.AddFromFile "D:\MSVC\BuildTools\Common7\IDE\vstlbinf.dll"`. Then VBE is able to autocomplete when typing `TLI.` but running a function using `Dim TLIApp As TLI.TLIApplication` I get the error "Class not registered" when reaching `Set TLIApp = New TLI.TLIApplication`. This is the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42581513/6421445

Comment: @FredEric That means you have 64-bit Office. Using 32-bit libraries in 64-bit Office is an entirely separate problem not specific to TypeLib Information.