# Get list of all properties for an Excel object in Windows 10

Tags: vba, excel

I would like to list all properties for an Excel Chart object, and I found a question with a solution:
[Get list of all properties for an object](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19783180/750172)
but it seems that this solution does not work on Windows 10 (and I think it does not work on Windows 7). The dll for TypeLib Information is apparently not compatible with Windows 10.

I use Office 2003, 2010 and 2013, and Windows 7 and 10. If you have a suggestion then please specify which version your suggested solution is tested on or expected to work on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't found an answer for VBA, but in AutoIt [autoit](/questions/tagged/autoit) it is possible to do something like this (requires that you select the first property in the Object browser (e.g. select Activate of the Chart object).

```
#include <GuiListBox.au3>
_ReadItems() 
Func _ReadItems()

    const $delay=100
    ;;get handle to Object Browser window
    $hwnd=WinWait("Microsoft Visual Basic - Book1 - [Object Browser]")
    ;;get handle to Object list box
    Local $hLB = ControlGetHandle($hwnd,"","[CLASS:ListBox; INSTANCE:3]")

    ;;get handle to "property information box"
    Local $hInfo= ControlGetHandle($hwnd,"","[CLASS:RichEdit20A; INSTANCE:1]")

    Local $sMsg = ""
    Local  $text=""
    ;; loop through all items in list
    Local  $iCnt =_GUICtrlListBox_GetCount ( $hLB )
    For $n = 0 To  $iCnt - 1
      sleep($delay)
      ;;copy text in information box
      ControlFocus($hWnd, "",$hInfo)
      sleep($delay)
      send("^a")
      sleep($delay)
      send("^c")
      sleep($delay)
      $text= ClipGet()
      ;;move down in object list box
      send("+{TAB}")
      sleep($delay)
      send("{DOWN}")
      ;;add information to result string
      $sMsg &=  $text & @CRLF
   Next 
  ;;put result on clipboard
    ClipPut($sMsg)
 EndFunc   ;==>_ReadItems
```