# Can't get value from DatePicker

Tags: vba, excel

I have a DatePicker control on a worksheet.  When I'm in the embedded code for the worksheet, I can access the control's value as follows:

```
Public Sub showValue()

Debug.Print Me.DTPicker21.value

End Sub
```

I would like to get the value from a module.  Code here:

```
Sub getDate()

Dim obj As Object
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool interface")
For Each obj In sht.OLEObjects
    If obj.Name = "DTPicker21" Then
        Debug.Print obj.value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

When I run this, the `obj.value` triggers this error:

```
Object doesn't support this property or method
```

I checked the list of properties for `obj` using [this procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19783297/619177), and there is no `value` property.  How can I get the date value that's been set in the DatePicker?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know all of the details, but some of the `OLEObjects` require that you first access their `Object` property, then you can access other properties. I think the OLEObject serves as a container, then the "sub-object" is the actual object with which you want to interact. For example, if you run the following two lines of code, you will see that the first returns `OleObject` and the second returns `DTPicker`:

```
Debug.Print "Obj: " & TypeName(obj)
Debug.Print "Obj.Object: " & TypeName(obj.Object)
```

In your case, try the following code change to remove the error(note the Debug line):

```
Sub getDate()

Dim obj As Object
Dim sht As Worksheet

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Tool interface")
For Each obj In sht.OLEObjects
    If obj.Name = "DTPicker21" Then
        Debug.Print obj.Object.Value
    End If
Next

End Sub
```