# Passing object to function in VB 6

Tags: vb6

```
Dim xyzWkB As Excel.workbook
Set xyzWkB = setGetxyzObj(reportFile.Text)
populateListCombo (xyzWkB)
```

The function is defined as follows:

```
Public Function populateListCombo(activeWkB As Excel.workbook)
......
......
End Function
```

But in execution at the time of calling `populateListCombo` am getting the error **"object does not support this property"**

Here `setGetxyzObj` is defined as follows:

```
Public Function setGetxyzObj(Optional userInput As String) As Excel.workbook
    Static xyz As New Excel.Application
    Static xyzWkB As Excel.workbook
    Set xyz = New Excel.Application
    If Not (userInput = "") Then
        Set xyzWkB = xyz.Workbooks.Open(userInput)
    End If
    Set setGetxyzObj = xyzWkB
End Function
```

I have also tried with `populateListCombo (setGetxyzObj())`, but still getting the same error.

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA Adding a class to a collection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6331106/vba-adding-a-class-to-a-collection)

Comment: Did you try to call  `populateListCombo` withou *any* parentheses? In Vb6 you should generally not use them when calling methods (as opposed to functions)

Comment: calling populateListCombo without parentheses also did not work.