# cant assign a shape to a Class object in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to create a class that will handle shapes (and other things). below is the part of my class that handle shapes (each object in my class has a shape associated with it, i want to be able to store and call it when needed).
CLass (CShapes):

```
Option Explicit
Private m_Shape As Shape

Public Property Get Shape() As Shape

    Set Shape = m_Shape

End Property

Public Property Let Shape(ByVal pShape As Shape)

    Set m_Shape = pShape

End Property
```

my function/method:

```
Sub CustomShapes()
    Dim star As New CShapes ' Declare and instantiate the CShapes object
    Dim shp1 As Shape
    Set shp1 = ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddShape(msoShape16pointStar, _
        ActiveCell.Left, ActiveCell.Top, 80, 27)
    Set star.Shape = shp1 ' Set the Shape property of the CShapes object
End Sub
```

i get an error "Object variable or with Block not set" in line "Set star.Shape = shp1". not sure why. im suspecting something in the way i defined the class is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try using Property Set, instead of Property Let...

```
Public Property Set Shape(ByVal pShape As Shape)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
Set star.Shape = shp1
```

into

```
star.Shape = shp1
```

otherwise you would ask the CShape to return an object which should be set as shp1 (which can't be done this way). If you notice, with `Set star.Shape = shp1` the `Get` is activated. With `star.Shape = shp1` the `Let` is activated.

Comment: That is correct, although object properties should use the `Set` keyword. Not sure why it was downvoted.

Comment: @KostasK. In truth i didn't really pay much attention to the use of `Let` instead of `Set`. Took the code as it was, tested, edited, reported it. I just wanted a "cookie-like" problem to solve before going to sleep. I've never used `Let` either.

Comment: It is allowed, although it can get confusing. The `Set` keyword clearly denotes this is an object.

Comment: @KostasK. It was downvoted because it's wrong. You [cannot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26891780/11683) assign an instance of `Shape` to a `Shaped`-typed property with `star.Shape = shp1`. What that does is assigning the [value of the default property of one `Shape` to that same property of another `Shape`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6331106/11683) - which won't work because `Shape` does not have a default property. Why it was upvoted though is a complete mystery to me. This code causes either error 91 or error 438, depending on whether `star.Shape` already contains a `Shape`.

Comment: @GSerg Is this for shapes only or general object assignment?

Comment: @KostasK. For general object assignment. See e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200523/11683 and follow the links from there.

Comment: @GSerg I don't get it. The code seems to work to me. If i add the line `star.Shape.Top = 200` after `star.Shape = shp1` it does move the shape. The `Let` do actually "set" the shape in the line `Set m_Shape = pShape`, so what am i missing?

Comment: I stand corrected, VBA is being overly helpful here and allows you to invoke the `Property Let` and immediately defeat its purpose by using `Set` from inside of it. It is still wrong to do that - it makes the use of `CShapes` look backwards to how it works everywhere else in VBA, that is, it *makes* you not use `Set` in a context where `Set` [*must*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19200523/11683) be used. Your explanation of "which can't be done this way" is wrong too - the behaviour you observe is due to the lack of `Property Set`. Try having *both* `Property Let` and `Property Set`.

Comment: @GSerg I mean: it can't be done that way... again: it literally can't be done that way because if you try it doesn't work. It's "evoking an object" and then asking it to be changed. Kind like trying to put in a snack in a snack vending machine in order to obtain another snack. It doesn't work that way. It wasn't much an explanation as it was a matter of fact. One can't `Set` (or `Let`) something while using a `Get` on that thing.

Comment: The `Get` in your class is only being invoked because you are missing `Property Set`. If you add both `Property Let` and `Property Set` to that class, `Get` will not be invoked, and the assignment will work as it should. And you will have a weird class whose object-typed property can be assigned both with and without `Set`. Now, if your goal was to create such class, then fine; but you are saying that the right way of allowing the assignment is to just use `Property Let`. That is not true. The right way is to use `Property Set` like in the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/78064209).

Comment: @GSerg I said it quite clearly in my first comment. Let me quote «In truth i didn't really pay much attention to the use of `Let` instead of `Set`. Took the code as it was, tested, edited, reported it». I've never suggested that `Let` should be used or that the code as it is is formally correct. Point was: is it working? It wasn't: is it the "right" way? It's like saying that using a single letter variable is the "wrong" way. Tecnically it will still work, but formally it's not "right". I've never used `Let` in my coding before and please quote exactly where did i raccomended it.

Comment: There is a difference between "not the right way" and "the wrong way". This is "the wrong way". The only thing it achieves is making the next guy who sees that code think "wtf" and spend several precious minutes of their life to understand why *that* was done.

Comment: @GSerg Actually, there is no difference at all between not the right way and the wrong way as long as you treat right and wrong as boolean variable. And i'm quite confident that the next person that will see that code the next time will most likely be the questioner herself which might have a WTF moment eventually thanks to her programming skills being improved in the meantime. Other than that, provided that the code works (since, again, it does) nobody will spend their precious time trying to debugging the first "non righteously yet still working" attempt of a shape-handling class.

Comment: That being said, i appriciate your concern over an also "formally right" solution. I understand the importance of a valid coding etiquette even if without it a code still is working. I'm just like: if you expect the solution to be "right", please consider to have the same expectation in your critique. Don't call my solution solution wrong because it wont' work and it will cause an error, while it works. Don't say my "explanation" is wrong while i am simply stating the fact that led to the question.

Comment: Don't say i've racommended the use of Let instead of Set. I've written in my second comment and quoted again later. I took the code and made the minimal change i've come up with before going to bed. The code was working? Good enouth. I wasn't here to dispense a critique on the right way to code, going like "the code is missing Option Explicit on the function section, this is the wrong way" or "star is a bad name without a prefix to identify the type of variable, this is the wrong way" or "no spacing between the line makes the code less readable, this is the wrong way".